# Vim Plugin - Easymotion isn't starting automatically

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc, plugin

I'm trying to improve my neovim with plugins and the best plugin that I found is Easymotion. However, it do not start automatically. I need to do :`source ~/.vimrc` every time that I launch a file. How can I fix this? Other plugins need to be read only once.

Plugin manager - VimPlug.
OS - RHEL8

here is my .vimrc file, and yes, I symlinked to init.vim in NeoVim. Actually, I had this problem both in Vim and Neovim.

```
 1 set number
 2 set expandtab
 3 set tabstop=2
 4 set incsearch
 5 call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
 6 Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
 7 Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
 8 Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
 9 Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
10 Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
11 Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
12 Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
13 Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
14 Plug 'rking/ag.vim'
15 call plug#end()
16 map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
17 map <Leader> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
18 let g:mapleader=','
19 syntax on
20 colorscheme gruvbox
21 set background=dark
22 set rtp^=/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/
```

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] StackExchange for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you're redefining the mapleader to `,` *after* you create a mapping using `<Leader>`. So your mapping is created with the default mapleader, which is `\`.

When you source vimrc for the second time, it will recreate that mapping, but now use the updated mapleader of `,` which was set on the first run of the vimrc file.

To solve the issue, simply invert the order of these two lines:

```
let g:mapleader=','
map <Leader> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
```